# Communications link failure with Docker-compose

Tags: mysql, jdbc, docker-compose

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql) and similar questions don't solve my question.

I'm trying to connect my application to a MySQL server to no avail.
I can't seem to find the error that causes this connection failure.

This is the full error log:
https://pastebin.com/t54pVb58

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mysql-ricette:
    container_name: mysqlRicette
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ricette
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  ricette-service:
    container_name: ricette
    build: ./ricette
    depends_on:
      - consul
      - mysql-ricette
      - kafka
      - zookeeper
```

This is my application.yml for ricette-service:
https://pastebin.com/PNhF532g

And this is the Entity I'd like to save in the database:

```
@Entity 
@Data @NoArgsConstructor
public class RicettaCompleta {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id; 
    private String autore; 
    private String titolo; 
    private String preparazione; 
    
    public RicettaCompleta(String autore, String titolo, String preparazione) {
        this(); 
        this.autore = autore; 
        this.titolo = titolo; 
        this.preparazione = preparazione; 
    }
    
}
```

I know that this error means that something is wrong with the datasource configuration. But I have no idea what.
Yes the mysql-ricette DB is actually running.

Please help my fix this error that I keep getting.

Comment: Can you post your datasource url?

Comment: url: jdbc:mysql://mysql-ricette:3306/ricette

Comment: Can you connect to the DB from the host?

Comment: Yes, I have no troubles with the DB itself

Comment: How are you initializing the HikariDataSource?  Can you post your application props?

Comment: It's linked in the question, I use this application.yml: https://pastebin.com/PNhF532g

Comment: Ah sorry I missed that link, that looks ok.  How are you initializing your Hikari datasource?

Answer (score 0):

you need to link mysql-ricette to ricette-service. updated yml file looks like this. also replace your mysql url in java code as well, ie. your application.yml or application.properties whichever you are using with `jdbc:mysql://mysql-ricette:3306/ricette?serverTimezone=UTC`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mysql-ricette:
    container_name: mysqlRicette
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ricette
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  ricette-service:
    container_name: ricette
    build: ./ricette
    depends_on:
      - consul
      - mysql-ricette
      - kafka
      - zookeeper
    links: 
      - mysql-ricette
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` and `mysql` to `mysql:5.7` did the trick.
I understand the first change because the driver is deprecated, but I don't get the mysql one.

Comment: It may be that driver isn't the latest either.  Using "mysql" in the image will use latest version which currently is 8.x, but if the driver you are using is "Connector/J 5.1" I don't believe that supports mysql 8.x.  Take a look at this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-whats-new.html.

Comment: Switching from `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` cannot have fixed this problem, as loading `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` will load `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`.